# Building a DART Interop over DATAJS for ODATA support

Tags: dart, interop, datajs

I would like to understand how to build a DART library that wraps [DataJS](http://datajs.codeplex.com/) as I would like to get ODATA support within DART.

What is the best approach to building a DART to JS Interop or is there an existing DART library out there I can utilize?

Cheers

Comment: You can search for `[dart-js-interop]` here on StackOverflow. Can you please improve your question. Questions for external resources are discouraged on StackOverflow. You can search pub.dartlang.org for Dart packages. Your question should be about a concrete programming problem and possibly contain code that demonstrates what you have already tried. Now it's merely a question like 'give me some code' which is discouraged on SO as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have searched pub.darling.org, there are no packages of this nature.  I am new to DART so providing a code example for the very thing I seek is not something I am easily able to do. I attempted to run JSParser over Data.jS and although I ended up with a parsed version it was not a very usable product.

Comment: As for code this is a small sample of the code generated by jsparser when run against data.js ..../* Program */
((function (window<0>, undefined<1>)
{
  var datajs<2> = (window<0>["datajs"]||<3>({}));
  var odata<4> = (window<0>["OData"]||<3>({}));
  if ((((typeof<5>define<6>)===<7>'function')&&<8>define<6>["amd"]))
  {
    (define<6>('datajs', datajs<2>));
    (define<6>('OData', odata<4>));
  }
  else
  {
    (window<0>["datajs"]datajs<2>);
    (window<0>["OData"]odata<4>);
  }

  (datajs<2>["version"]({"major": 1, "minor": 1, "build": 1}));

Comment: As yo can see yourself (I hope ;-) ) putting code in a comment is not very readable. Please edit your question and add the code there. You can find the `edit` link below the tags ([dart][interop]]datajs]).

Comment: You could add the equivalent JavaScript code you need to call then it will be probably easier to provide code how one would do this in Dart. In its current state your question is just to broad for StackOverflow. 
see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://sscce.org/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269